# TVDigitEntryViewController - Can only select first digit

Tags: swift, swiftui, tvos, tvuikit

I am implementing `TVDigitEntryViewController` within SwiftUI. The screen renders properly, however, although the selection area shows numbers 1-0 plus backspace, I can only focus on the number `1`. Any right swipes are refused and the focus sticks with the #1 only.

The code is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import TVUIKit

struct LinkAccountView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        return LinkAccountVC()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {

    }
}

class LinkAccountVC: TVDigitEntryViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.numberOfDigits = 4
        self.titleText = "Link Code"
        entryCompletionHandler = { (enteredCode) in
            print("Code:\(enteredCode)")
        }
    }
}
```

Update: Implementing without SwiftUI works so the issue is definitely SwiftUI for some reason.

Here is a full sample project that can be used to demonstrate the issue:

```
import SwiftUI  
import TVUIKit  


struct ContentView: View {  
    var body: some View {  
        VStack {  
            Spacer()  
            NavigationView {  
                List {  
                    NavigationLink(destination: LinkAccountView()) {  
                        HStack {  
                            Image(systemName: "link")  
                                .font(.headline)  
                            Text("Link Account")  
                                .font(.headline)  
                        }  
                    }  
                }  
                .padding()  
                .navigationBarTitle("Settings")  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}  


struct LinkAccountView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {  

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> TVDigitEntryViewController {  
        return LinkAccountVC()  
    }  

    func updateUIViewController(_ viewController: TVDigitEntryViewController, context: Context) {  


    }  
}  


class LinkAccountVC: TVDigitEntryViewController {  
    override func viewDidLoad() {  
        super.viewDidLoad()  

        self.numberOfDigits = 4  
        self.titleText = "Link Code"  
        entryCompletionHandler = { (enteredCode) in  
            print("Code:\(enteredCode)")  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue?

Comment: @JoostvandenAkker - Unfortunately no. I used UIKit for this piece at the time. Given it was nearly a year ago and SwiftUI has since been updated and perhaps it has been resolved. However, if you are asking this question now I assume it hasn't....